# Set dependecy for javaagent eclipselink.jar in Eclipse Tomcat and CentOs

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, centos, eclipselink

I am using eclipse, tomcat and eclipselink to develop web application. I need to configure `javaagent:eclipselink.jar` on eclipse java VM to enable Weaving on eclipselink.

On Eclipse's VM arguments I add `-javaagent:/Users/user/Development/lib/eclipselink/2.7.10/eclipselink.jar`. When I run the tomcat server, I get error messege

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:491)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:503)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceUnitInfo
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.JavaSECMPInitializerAgent.initializeFromAgent(JavaSECMPInitializerAgent.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.JavaSECMPInitializerAgent.premain(JavaSECMPInitializerAgent.java:41)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 10 more
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "result" with message agent load/premain call failed at open/src/java.instrument/share/native/libinstrument/JPLISAgent.c line: 422
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed, processJavaStart failed
```

When I run UnitTest with `-javaagent:/Users/user/Development/lib/eclipselink/2.7.10/eclipselink.jar` configuration, it run without error.

When I run tomcat with `-Djavaagent:/Users/user/Development/lib/eclipselink/2.7.10/eclipselink.jar` configuration, it run but I don't the weaving function is no enable to jpa queries.

I use :

- java 17 SE
- tomcat 9.0.56
- eclipselink 2.7.10 (for JPA)
- mysql 8.0.28
- macos ventura

How to setting javaaggent with dipendecies?
Can anyone help me with this situation?
How to configurate eclipselink.jar to enable weaving?

I think, `the eclipselink.jar` has dipendency with another jar file (`jakarta.persistence_2.2.3.jar`). How can I configure this in CentOS ?

**Update:**
I found a solution from this page [github eclipselink issue #1803](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/eclipselink/issues/1803) how to add dipendency on JVM argument.

```
-Xbootclasspath/a:plugins/jakarta.persistence-api_3.1.0.jar
```

At my situation:

```
-Xbootclasspath/a:/eclipselink/2.7.13/jakarta.persistence_2.2.3.jar -javaagent:/eclipselink/2.7.13/eclipselink_2.7.13.jar
```

I think, it works. The error is diappear.

Comment: Are  you using a build tool? Are you including your dependencies?

Comment: I am using maven dependencies and build war file from eclipse.

Comment: @dan1st I think the eclipselink.jar file has dipendency with an other jar file. Do you know how to configure this in CentOS?

Comment: If you are using maven, why are you not building the WAR file with Maven?

Comment: because the jar file must be loaded on jvm startup (base on documentation `https://eclipse.dev/eclipselink/documentation/2.6/solutions/testingjpa004.htm`). So, I must set with -javaagent on VM argument. But the jar file have dependency with an other jar file. I don't know, how to menage this on the server.

Comment: And how does the way the JAR file is loaded influence the way you are building it?

Comment: You might try a different approach: static weaving your entities. See https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Tomcat_Web_Tutorial and https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Performance/Weaving/Static_Weaving as I don't know that you'll get dynamic weaving to work in Tomcat which is not a full EE server. Ps EclipseLink 2.7 will require Javax persistence, not Jakarta.